# Angular2 Script does not work in update form although it is working in the List and add forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-mvc-4, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have created an MVC project then I added the angulare2 files to it 
then I have created 2 pure html pages one for (add / edit) actions and the second is for list
When I click on a row the key should be passed in the url (query string) to redirect to the (add / edit) page to load the data.

the problem is that the Angular2 Script does not work with the edit (data in not loaded) although it is working with the List and add
here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { SubscriberService } from '../Service/subscriber.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { IScubscriber } from '../Models/Subscriber';
import { DBOperation } from '../Shared/enum';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Global } from '../Shared/global';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


 @Component({

templateUrl: 'app/Views/Subscriber/Mangage.subscriber.html'

//templateUrl:'Home/testRoutes'
})


export class ManageSubscriberComponent implements OnInit {
Subscriber: IScubscriber;
Subscribers: IScubscriber[];
msg: string;
indLoading: boolean = false;
subscriberFrm: FormGroup;
dbops: DBOperation;
Title: string;
BtnTitle: string;
id: number;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _SubscriberService: SubscriberService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }



ngOnInit(): void {

    this.subscriberFrm = this.fb.group({
        Id: [''],
        Name: ['', Validators.required],
        NameOther: [''],
        Address: [''],
        AddressOther: [''],
        Phone1: [''],
        Phone2: [''],
        IsActive: ['', Validators.required],
        IsDeleted: [''],
        CreatedBy: [''],
        CreatedIn: [''],
        UpdatedBy: [''],
        UpdatedIn: [''],

    });

    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    if (isNaN(this.id)) {
        this.addSubscriber();
    }
    else {
        this.editSubscriber(this.id);
    }
}

addSubscriber() {
    this.dbops = DBOperation.create;
    this.SetControlsState(true);
    this.Title = "Add New Subscriber";
    this.BtnTitle = "Add";
    this.subscriberFrm.reset();
    //this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
}

editSubscriber(id: number) {
    this.dbops = DBOperation.update;
    this.SetControlsState(true);
    this.Title = "Edit Subscriber";
    this.BtnTitle = "Update";
    //this.indLoading = true;
    this._SubscriberService.getById(Global.BASE_SUBSCRIBER_ENDPOINT, id)
        .subscribe(Subscriber => { this.Subscriber = Subscriber; this.indLoading = false; },
        error => this.msg = <any>error);
    //this.Subscriber = this.Subscribers.filter(x => x.Id == id)[0];
    console.log(this.Subscriber);
    this.subscriberFrm.setValue(this.Subscriber);
    //  this.modal.open();
}

//deleteSubscriber(id: number) {
//    this.dbops = DBOperation.delete;
//    this.SetControlsState(false);
//    this.Title = "Confirm to Delete?";
//    this.BtnTitle = "Delete";
//    this.Subscriber = this.Subscribers.filter(x => x.Id == id)[0];
//    this.subscriberFrm.setValue(this.Subscriber);
//    this.modal.open();
//}
onSubmit(formData: any) {
    this.msg = "";

    switch (this.dbops) {
        case DBOperation.create:
            this._SubscriberService.post(Global.BASE_SUBSCRIBER_ENDPOINT, formData._value).subscribe(
                data => {
                    if (data == 1) //Success
                    {
                        this.msg = "Data successfully added.";
                        //this.LoadSubscribers();
                    }
                    else {
                        this.msg = "There is some issue in saving records, please contact to system administrator!"
                    }

                    //this.modal.dismiss();
                },
                error => {
                    this.msg = error;
                }
            );
            break;
        case DBOperation.update:
            this._SubscriberService.put(Global.BASE_SUBSCRIBER_ENDPOINT, formData._value.Id, formData._value).subscribe(
                data => {
                    if (data == 1) //Success
                    {
                        this.msg = "Data successfully updated.";
                        //this.LoadSubscribers();
                    }
                    else {
                        this.msg = "There is some issue in saving records, please contact to system administrator!"
                    }

                    //this.modal.dismiss();
                },
                error => {
                    this.msg = error;
                }
            );
            break;
        case DBOperation.delete:
            this._SubscriberService.delete(Global.BASE_SUBSCRIBER_ENDPOINT, formData._value.Id).subscribe(
                data => {
                    if (data == 1) //Success
                    {
                        this.msg = "Data successfully deleted.";
                        //this.LoadSubscribers();
                    }
                    else {
                        this.msg = "There is some issue in saving records, please contact to system administrator!"
                    }

                    //this.modal.dismiss();
                },
                error => {
                    this.msg = error;
                }
            );
            break;

    }
}


SetControlsState(isEnable: boolean) {

    isEnable ? this.subscriberFrm.enable() : this.subscriberFrm.disable();
 }

 }
```

[The List page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6DUS.png)
[The Add/ Edit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csw6y.png)
the routing script:

```
               import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
           import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
           import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component';
           import { SubscriberComponent } from './components/subscriber.component';
           import { ManageSubscriberComponent } from './Components/manage.subsciber.component'

           const appRoutes: Routes = [    
           { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
           { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
           { path: 'subscriber', component: SubscriberComponent },
           { path: 'managesubscriber/:id', component: ManageSubscriberComponent },
           { path: 'managesubscriber', component: ManageSubscriberComponent },

           ];

           export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand, but it is important to remember that if your service is performing an Http call, that call is asynchronous. So the code after the subscribe will execute *BEFORE* the data is retrieved. I numbered the sequence below:

```
this._SubscriberService.getById(Global.BASE_SUBSCRIBER_ENDPOINT, id) // (1)
    .subscribe(Subscriber => { this.Subscriber = Subscriber; this.indLoading = false; //(4) },
    error => this.msg = <any>error);
console.log(this.Subscriber);  // (2)
this.subscriberFrm.setValue(this.Subscriber); //(3)
```

To solve this issue, you can add all of the required code within the first subscribe method:

```
this._SubscriberService.getById(Global.BASE_SUBSCRIBER_ENDPOINT, id)
    .subscribe(Subscriber => 
       { 
         this.Subscriber = Subscriber; this.indLoading = false;
         //this.Subscriber = this.Subscribers.filter(x => x.Id == id)[0];
         console.log(this.Subscriber);
         this.subscriberFrm.setValue(this.Subscriber);
       },
    error => this.msg = <any>error);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation it have worked successfully 
and thank for your pluralsite courses

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Can you mark this as your answer so this question is closed? Thanks!

Comment: I upvote the question but I see the message "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Hmmm. As the original poster  (OP) you should be able to mark your own question as answered ... even with very few reputation points. Note that marking the question as answered is different from upvoting it.